# On my MacBook Pro, why are my apps taking forever to launch and my webpages taking forever to begin to load?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, google-chrome

I have a MacBook Pro 2018 with fairly maxed out specs.  Over the past couple months, I've been having two potentially related issues...

1. My apps frequently take a long time to launch, the kind of thing where the app's icon will bounce in the dock for 20 seconds before the app actually launches.  Once the apps are launched, I don't have any issues with sluggishness, and they work fine.  It's just this wait for them to actually launch.
2. Webpages take a long time to begin to load.  I use Chrome, and the browser just sort of sits there seemingly doing nothing for 10 seconds, and then finally connects to the webpage.  Once it begins loading the webpage, it loads at normal speed, so the issue doesn't seem to be related to internet speeds or networking or anything like that.

I have no idea if these issues are related, but they seem related and started around the same time about a month ago.  I'd be grateful for any diagnosis on what this might be, and any tips on how to resolve these things.

Comment: Which macOS is it running? Do you have an SSD or and HDD?

Comment: Actually that sounds like an I/O related problem (EG reading from / writing to SSD). I would be tempted to boot into recovery mode and run a repair (a few times) on the disk and see if that helps. If not there may be something else going on. The first thing that springs to mind is a possible problem with the SSD, but with the limited info you provided it is hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks, @lhf.  I'm running Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveChambers.  I have an SSD.  I will try repairing the disk in macOS Recovery!